# Facebook like button not works correctly in single page web application

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I wanted to put like button in my web application.

Then I followed facebook Like button page.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

At the first time, the Like button not showed up correctly but it shows well after putting codes below.

```
FB.XFBML.parse();
```

When I click the Like button, Facebook can not get right information of the page.

I've already put meta tags(og:title, og:description) before Like button parsed.

[image]

How can I figure out this problem?

The Share buttons works great because I use FB.ui for the Share button.

Comment: it is nearly impossible to help you if you don´t come up with a test link

Comment: Thanks, I've added a test link.

Comment: You can not add the meta info client-side, and expect the FB scraper to pick up on that – it doesn’t execute JavaScript. If you want to share individual articles, then each of those articles needs an individual URL as well (and not the same URL, that differs only in the hash part, because that has only client-side relevance).

Comment: @CBore Thanks for the comment. Any good solution for single page web site?